# dot in parameter - Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am working on Lumen app where I have URL like this `http://localhost:8000/membership/61.515162.467` and I have defined URL like this.

```
$app->get('membership/{orderId:[0-9\.]+}', [
    'as' => 'membership', 'uses' => 'MembershipController@show'
]);
```

But apparently this is not working it is not matching anything. I am getting 404. Is there anyway to use `.` in parameter or is it not possible.

Comment: does there any exceptions?

Comment: Yes 404 not found exception

Comment: Can we have more info about your routes ?

Comment: I have put the route above. code snippet is the defined route.

Comment: I can confirm this works. Something else is wrong with you...

Comment: hmm its a fresh Lumen app. How are you running your dev server (though I doubt that is the issue).

Comment: `lumen new stack` then go to `http://stack.laravel.dev` ( i have magic work space xD )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141302/discussion-between-moein-porkamel-and-nicholasnet).

Comment: May be it's PHP dev internal server issue. Because in my case even script is not executed not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you @MoeinPorkamel for your help.